# VBA to input formula in code

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to convert the below `excel` formula into a vba code for macro but not sure what is the syntax to input the same in code
How to write a `VBA` code for the below formula

```
=CONCATENATE(A12,REPT(" ",(10-LEN(A12))),B12,REPT(" ",215))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the worksheet formula in VBA:

```
Sub qwerty()
    x = Evaluate("CONCATENATE(A12,REPT("" "",(10-LEN(A12))),B12,REPT("" "",215))")
    MsgBox x
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, tried the above but isnt working. This is the code i am trying Sub GEFU()
Dim Custid As Integer
Dim Pan As String

Cells(x, 3) = Evaluate("CONCATENATE(A12,REPT("" "",(10-LEN(A12))),B12,REPT("" "",215))")

Range("A1:B10").Copy
Shell "notepad.exe", vbNormalFocus
SendKeys "^V"
End Sub